# How to embed Youtube link in Odoo using upload button?

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, odoo, odoo-10

Currently, I am able to embed the single video using this iframe and for every time I have to write this code in the view.

`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AmTjku8n_DQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Now, I want to add upload button at attachment field. So, the user can upload any video and it will be directly embedded in my UI-view.

[image]

In Odoo I am using `ir.attachment` model but it does not have a feature of embedding videos it only creates a hyperlink and redirects to next page.

How can we solve this issue? Any ideas are appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to understand what you exactly need , but here are the some module link that can help you.

https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/muk_web_preview_video/

https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/website_upload_video/

Comment: I want to embed YouTube links in a particular page. So i want to store id of that link in a database so how to do that.

Comment: have you try above modules ? it will do the same as you want

Comment: No I haven't try module. I'll try the module link given by ADVALAki

Answer (score 1):

the solution to your problem is here.
refer this module :
https://github.com/ADVALAKI/Odoo_Sample_Modules/tree/10.0/embed_video

Comment: This module is not working and showing error. Didn't solve my problem as it is redirecting URL to a new page which I don't want. 
I want to embed video in the desired view.

Comment: Thanks allot bro. Yes, you did the same way which I was looking for. Highly thankful to you. Kudos

Comment: When i am clicking on a `Watch  Video` button in a tree view it is showing error. Can you please check this? 
https://ibb.co/eDOwoa

Comment: its because in tree view button forgot underscore change it to "watch_this_video"

Comment: The video which you uploaded only that is working and when I am uploading video by myself then I am unable to watch the video. It shows blank view. https://ibb.co/huUBoa

Comment: Its because to watch youtube you need embedded url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153734/discussion-between-dheeraj-balodia-and-advalaki).